# PGF/TikZ plot: syntax and limit range of plotted function

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, tikz-datavisualization

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263991/74786) answer an example of multiple functions plot is provided, using `PGF/TikZ` and the `datavisualization` library. The [documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) seems not to deal with the following issues:

1) For each plot, the `x` range is defined as:

```
var x : interval [-0.5*pi:4];
```

This way, whatever the function is and whatever values it reaches in the `x` range, it will be forced to be plot.

Is it possible to also limit the `y`, that is the plotted range? I trivially tried

```
func y = tan(\value x r) : interval [0:4];
```

(to obtain function values no higher than `4` and no lower than `0`) but it gives error. Limiting the axis has no effects on the plot.

2) In

```
func y = sin(\value x r);
```

what is the final `r` used for? If I try to remove it, the plot is incorrect. Where can some information about this syntax be found?

Comment: Ti*k*Z assumes the arguments of `sin` etc. to be degrees, and as you can see from the plots, `r` converts radians to degrees.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: A little research reveals that this question has already been asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/247886/121799), but the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247904/121799) suggests that it doesn't really work. In more detail, `min value=-4` and `max value=4` are supported, but they prevent the plot not from overshooting, as mentioned in the pgfmanual in section 77.2.3. I also started to play with the `at start survey` keys and the like, attempting to clip on the `data visualization bounding box`. Yet this was not successful. So in the end the only thing I can offer here is the very ad hoc way to confine the tan plot is to plot `max(min(tan(\value x r),4),-4)` instead, which only takes values between `-4` and `4`. As I mentioned above, `r` converts radians into degrees.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization [scientific axes=clean,
                    y axis={grid,min value=-4,max value=4},
                    visualize as smooth line/.list={sin,cos,tan},
                    style sheet=strong colors,
                    style sheet=vary dashing,
                    sin={label in legend={text=$\sin x$}},
                    cos={label in legend={text=$\cos x$}},
                    tan={label in legend={text=$\tan x$}},
                    data/format=function,
%                   at start survey={\clip (data visualization bounding
%                   box.south west) rectangle (data visualization bounding box.north east);}
                    ]
data [set=sin] {
  var x : interval [-0.5*pi:4];
  func y = sin(\value x r);
}
data [set=cos] {
  var x : interval [-0.5*pi:4];
  func y = cos(\value x r);
}
data [set=tan] {
  var x : interval [0:4];
  func y = max(min(tan(\value x r),4),-4);
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Perhaps someone else can make the commented out bit work....

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer and your attempts. I tried with 4 plots, [this](http://oi63.tinypic.com/142h5ow.jpg) is the output. The 3rd plot is `func y = max(min(tan(\value x r),4),-4);`, the 4th is simply `func y = tan(\value x r);`. Both the plots seem to have unusual blends around `pi/2`: the 3rd, an unusual "slow" slope before `pi/2`; the 4th, an unusual bending. Maybe the tangent itself is not easy to plot with `datavisualization`.

Comment: @BowPark My impression is (but I may be completely wrong) that pgfplots, which requires Ti*k*Z, is a better tool to do these things. The visualization stuff just lays the foundations.

Comment: After some small test plots, I definitely agree. They are different tools, but `pgfplot` fits more to this kind of task.